# Picking the right prometheus function to show graph of time measurements data

Tags: c#, grafana, prometheus

I have a `gauge` metric which I'm updating with the value of time that elapsed since starting of some processing, like that:

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

DoSomeProcessing();

watch.Stop();
_performanceGauge.Set(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

I would like that to be reflected in `grafana` dashboard but I'm having problems picking up correct function for this task. I thought about using the `idelta` function, but it results in a flat graph:

`idelta(bg_process_performance[2h])`

So which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a Gauge then you should display the raw value with no functions.

If you care about more than the most recent event, then you should use a Summary/Histogram instead and then calculate `irate(my_metric_sum[1m])/irate(my_metric_count[1m])` to get the average latency.